# D3 chart integration into Vuejs

Tags: d3.js, vue.js

I am trying to integrate [this](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/119a138ef9bd1d8f0a8d57ea72355252) D3 area graph into Vuejs and all I get from my code is the axes with a black area. It seems that the CSS properties have no effect on my graph and everything I have tried so far didn't change anything.. Most of the D3 graphs I have tried with Vuejs have similar problems.. Any ideas?

```
<template>
  <div class="line-chart"></div>
</template>

<script>
  import * as d3 from 'd3' 

  export default {
    name: 'line-chart',
    mounted () {
      this.renderChart()
    },
    data() {
      return {
        data: [
          { date: '1-May-12', close: 58.13 },
          { date: '30-Apr-12', close: 53.98 },
          { date: '27-Apr-12', close: 67.00 },
          { date: '26-Apr-12', close: 89.70 },
          { date: '25-Apr-12', close: 99.00 },
          { date: '24-Apr-12', close: 130.28 },
          { date: '23-Apr-12', close: 166.70 },
          { date: '20-Apr-12', close: 234.98 },
          { date: '19-Apr-12', close: 345.44 },
          { date: '18-Apr-12', close: 443.34 },
          { date: '17-Apr-12', close: 543.70 },
          { date: '16-Apr-12', close: 580.13 },
          { date: '13-Apr-12', close: 605.23 },
          { date: '12-Apr-12', close: 622.77 },
          { date: '11-Apr-12', close: 626.20 },
          { date: '10-Apr-12', close: 628.44 },
          { date: '9-Apr-12', close: 636.23 },
          { date: '5-Apr-12', close: 633.68 },
          { date: '4-Apr-12', close: 624.31 },
          { date: '3-Apr-12', close: 629.32 },
          { date: '2-Apr-12', close: 618.63 },
          { date: '30-Mar-12', close: 599.55 },
          { date: '29-Mar-12', close: 609.86 },
          { date: '28-Mar-12', close: 617.62 },
          { date: '27-Mar-12', close: 614.48 },
          { date: '26-Mar-12', close: 606.98 }
        ],
        width: 960,
        height: 500 
      }
    },
    methods: {
      renderChart() {
        var data = this.data;
        var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 }
        var width = this.width - margin.left - margin.right;
        var height = this.height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        var parseTime = d3.timeParse('%d-%b-%y');

        // parse the date / time
        var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");

        // set the ranges
        var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

        // define the area
        var area = d3.area()
          .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
          .y0(height)
          .y1(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

        // define the line
        var valueline = d3.line()
          .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
          .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
          .attr(
             "transform",
             "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        // format the data
        data.forEach(function(d) {
          d.date = parseTime(d.date);
          d.close = +d.close;
        });

        // scale the range of the data
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

        // add the area
        svg.append("path")
          .data([data])
          .attr("class", "area")
          .attr("d", area);

        // add the valueline path.
        svg.append("path")
          .data([data])
          .attr("class", "line")
          .attr("d", valueline);

        // add the X Axis
        svg.append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

        // add the Y Axis
        svg.append("g")
          .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
      },
    }
  };
</script>

<style scoped>
  .line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2px;
  }

  .area {
    fill: lightsteelblue;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: where is the `style` stuff that you define? Use the browser developer tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your div from a class of line-chart to an id of line-chart, then, where you have `d3.select('body')`, change it to `d3.select('#line-chart')`. That should append the graph to the write place.

Also, make sure you've installed d3v4 and not d3v3. There are serious breaking changes.

Edited to add: here's a working example in the Stack Overflow snippet runner thing. It's not a single-file component anymore but it's essentially identical.

```js
new Vue({
      el: '#line-chart',
      mounted () {
        this.renderChart()
        setTimeout(()=>{
              this.data = [
              { date: '1-May-12', close: 58.13 },
              { date: '30-Apr-12', close: 53.98 },
              { date: '27-Apr-12', close: 67.00 },
              { date: '26-Apr-12', close: 89.70 },
              { date: '25-Apr-12', close: 99.00 },
              { date: '24-Apr-12', close: 130.28 },
              { date: '23-Apr-12', close: 166.70 },
              { date: '20-Apr-12', close: 234.98 },
              { date: '19-Apr-12', close: 345.44 },
              { date: '18-Apr-12', close: 443.34 },
              { date: '17-Apr-12', close: 543.70 },
              { date: '16-Apr-12', close: 580.13 },
              { date: '13-Apr-12', close: 605.23 },
              { date: '12-Apr-12', close: 622.77 },
              { date: '11-Apr-12', close: 626.20 },
              { date: '10-Apr-12', close: 628.44 },
              { date: '9-Apr-12', close: 636.23 },
              { date: '5-Apr-12', close: 633.68 },
              { date: '4-Apr-12', close: 624.31 },
              { date: '3-Apr-12', close: 629.32 },
              { date: '2-Apr-12', close: 618.63 },
              { date: '30-Mar-12', close: 599.55 },
              { date: '29-Mar-12', close: 609.86 },
              { date: '28-Mar-12', close: 617.62 },
              { date: '27-Mar-12', close: 614.48 },
              { date: '26-Mar-12', close: 606.98 }
             ]}, 1000)
      },
      data() {
        return {
              data: [],
              width: 960,
              height: 500 
          }
      },
      methods: {
        renderChart() {
          if (document.getElementsByTagName('svg')){
              d3.selectAll('svg').remove()
          }
          var data = this.data;
          var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 }
          var width = this.width - margin.left - margin.right;
          var height = this.height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
          var parseTime = d3.timeParse('%d-%b-%y');

          // parse the date / time
    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");

    
    // set the ranges
    var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

    // define the area
    var area = d3.area()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y0(height)
        .y1(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

    // define the line
    var valueline = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

    var svg = d3.select("#line-chart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      // format the data
      data.forEach(function(d) {
          d.date = parseTime(d.date);
          d.close = +d.close;
      });

      // scale the range of the data
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

      // add the area
        svg.append("path")
           .data([data])
           .attr("class", "area")
           .attr("d", area);

      // add the valueline path.
      svg.append("path")
          .data([data])
          .attr("class", "line")
          .attr("d", valueline);

      // add the X Axis
      svg.append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

      // add the Y Axis
      svg.append("g")
          .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
      },
     },
     watch: {
     data(val) {
      if (val){
        this.renderChart()
      }
     }
    }
})
```

```css
.line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    .area {
      fill: lightsteelblue;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.5.0/d3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="line-chart"></div>
```

Comment: I am using d3 v5 and everything seems ok with my code except that the css properties have no effect and the area is black. I am trying to understand why is this happening

Comment: I just edited the snippet so it's using d3 v5.5.0. If you run it, you'll see the chart is rendering. I've also tested the CSS properties in the dev tools, and they are working as well. (I changed the `area {fill: lightsteelblue}` to say `{fill: green}` and it did indeed turn green.) So I would think the change you should try is selecting the div element rather than the body.

Comment: The problem is the watchers. The data is loaded once in the mounted function renderChart() and then it turns black because there are no watchers to update the chart.. I mean I suspect this

Comment: so in your actual example, are you loading the data from an API call or something? I just updated the pen to try to imitate that. In mounted it runs the renderChart function, but the data isn't there yet, so it draws the axes. Then after a 1000 ms timeout, it sets the data to actual values. THEN, I added a watcher for the data property (see the bottom of the JS code) that redraws the chart whenever there's updated data.